# Picklist cotrol to create a new record

Tags: salesforce, record, picklist

'm working on a project to manage the human ressources, well my question is: how can I control a picklist to create a new record. Exemple: I go to Application tab, wich contain a picklist, among values I choose 'Time Off'. I want to redirect me to create a Time Off form ( Start date , End date ... etc) on a object Time off that 've already created.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to one solution showing a button where the record type is being set instead of being allowed to default:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008kdbIAA

The key is that parameter "p3" is the record type.  You'll need to replace the code segment

```
"p3" = "012500000009Wjw"
```

with something like

```
"p3" = IF ( ISPICKVAL(TypeToCreate, "Time Off"), "<record type id of TimeOff>", "<default record type (or nest more IFs>"
```

You could also use Visualforce and Apex for this.